# intermittent ERROR, Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5]

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, database-connection, scheduled-tasks, sql-server-2017

I have a .vbs script which is carrying out some modelling. This script is fired via a windows scheduled task and performs a fair amount of database selects, inserts and updates.

It has run many times over the years on SQL Server 2008 R2. Its now trying to run on win2016 Server running SQL Server 17.4. The job will run for a couple of hours ideally. Its stopping a little over an hour after almost 10,000 successful inserts, it throws me this error:

> Database Error: -2147467259 Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [5].

Is this SQL Server taking its resources back for some reason? Any ideas on resolving this would be very helpful?

Update : I have reduced the workload of the script. Instead of running for a couple of hours it now runs for less than one hour.  The first two runs have been successful, no issues.

Comment: I realize this is old but I suppose you were seeing this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/clients-change-protocols-when-connect-instance which would mean that, for some reason, the SQL Client could no longer connect using another protocol - presumably TCP/IP. There could be a lots of reason for that again but that's probably what's happening...

Answer (score 0):

i supose that you try to conect to another server  or  to the local server across with one computer with network , so check if you have this correct configuration :
[enter link description here](https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your time.  es thats correct, the WST/script runs on server A and the database is on server B on the same internal network.  I have had a look at the link.  I am not sure its relevant because the script successfully connects and works as expected for an hour or so, then I get the issue

Comment: Its rare, because for one hour or less their are conected, but try the configuration i'm post because its the correct way. Maybe the conection lost and the run, and DNS can find the  computer name, also is good put de ip adress into host file en windows with the name of the computer.